# vue2 flatpickr directive approach not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, flatpickr

I want to use [a simple directive](https://gist.github.com/chmln/e77b52cf0a719e18233ca7948be8fab4) to use [flatpickr](https://github.com/chmln/flatpickr) with vue.js, [like the author suggest here](https://github.com/chmln/flatpickr/issues/859#issuecomment-305362123):

```
import Flatpickr from "flatpickr";
import Vue from "vue";

// <input type="text" v-flatpickr="{'enableTime': true}"

Vue.directive("flatpickr", {
    bind: (el, binding) => {
        el._flatpickr = new Flatpickr(el, binding.value);
    },
    unbind: el => el._flatpickr.destroy()
});
```

I created [a simple fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/escapedcat/zcxbdg0n) to see if this works.
On the desktop it's all fine, but when switching to mobile-mode (via  chrome dev tools) and press "run" the needed input isn't created. Only the `hidden` input is created (see via inspect).

Anyone knows what this could cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {
    self.input.parentNode.insertBefore(self.mobileInput, self.input.nextSibling);
} catch (e) {
    //
}
```

self.input.parentNode === null

[It also returns null if the node has just been created and is not yet attached to the tree.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode)

Use **inserted** instead bind

```js
Vue.component('greeting', {
  template: '<div><input type="text" v-flatpickr="{}" /></div>'
});

Vue.directive('flatpickr', {
  inserted: (el, binding) => {
    el._flatpickr = new flatpickr(el, binding.value)
  },
  unbind: el => el._flatpickr.destroy()
})

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/chmln/flatpickr/v3.0.5-1/dist/flatpickr.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/chmln/flatpickr/v3.0.5-1/dist/flatpickr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="app">
  <greeting></greeting>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx for the extra explanaition. This approach works in my fiddle using the _directive_ approach. I wonder why it worked with `bind` for the author. Maybe a different version.